# How do I get number of parameters for TensorFlow Lite model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have an optimized TensorFlow Lite model which I load as

```
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=converted_model_path)
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

How do I get number of model parameters similar to keras's `model.count_params()`?

Comment: Hi! Could you check this thread for answer ? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46569